# How to maintain type parameter during TypeTag to Manifest conversion?

Tags: scala

Using the answer from this question, [Is it possible to convert a TypeTag to a Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383814/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-typetag-to-a-manifest), I can convert TypeTag to Manifest.

Unfortunately, using this method, you lose the Type Parameter. Due to the fact that you are using the runtimeClass to do the conversion. Here's a sample code that illustrate this point:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383814/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-typetag-to-a-manifest
def getManifestFromTypeTag[T:TypeTag] = {
  val t = typeTag[T]
  implicit val cl = ClassTag[T](t.mirror.runtimeClass(t.tpe))
  manifest[T]
}

// Soon to be deprecated way
def getManifest[T](implicit mf: Manifest[T]) = mf

getManifestFromTypeTag[String] == getManifest[String]
//evaluates to true

getManifestFromTypeTag[Map[String, Int]] == getManifest[Map[String, Int]]
//evalutes to false. Due the erasure.
```

Is there a way to retain the type parameters when converting from TypeTag to Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManifestFactory has a method called classType that allows create Manifest with type arguments.

Here's an implementation:

```
def toManifest[T:TypeTag]: Manifest[T] = {
  val t = typeTag[T]
  val mirror = t.mirror
  def toManifestRec(t: Type): Manifest[_] = {
    val clazz = ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t)).runtimeClass
    if (t.typeArgs.length == 1) {
      val arg = toManifestRec(t.typeArgs.head)
      ManifestFactory.classType(clazz, arg)
    } else if (t.typeArgs.length > 1) {
      val args = t.typeArgs.map(x => toManifestRec(x))
      ManifestFactory.classType(clazz, args.head, args.tail: _*)
    } else {
      ManifestFactory.classType(clazz)
    }
  }
  toManifestRec(t.tpe).asInstanceOf[Manifest[T]]
}
```

Comment: When I am using your code I get an error:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any

Comment: Improved version of `toManifest` is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673693/5249621