# In Scala 2.11+ reflection, how to reliably convert a TypeTag and a Manifest into each other?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-reflect

In this post:

[Is it possible to convert a TypeTag to a Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383814/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-typetag-to-a-manifest)

It is indicated that a TypeTag can be converted into a Manifest using the following code:

```
  def toManifest[T:TypeTag]: Manifest[T] = {
    val t = typeTag[T]
    val mirror = t.mirror
    def toManifestRec(t: Type): Manifest[_] = {
      val clazz = ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t)).runtimeClass
      if (t.typeArgs.length == 1) {
        val arg = toManifestRec(t.typeArgs.head)
        ManifestFactory.classType(clazz, arg)
      } else if (t.typeArgs.length > 1) {
        val args = t.typeArgs.map(x => toManifestRec(x))
        ManifestFactory.classType(clazz, args.head, args.tail: _*)
      } else {
        ManifestFactory.classType(clazz)
      }
    }
    toManifestRec(t.tpe).asInstanceOf[Manifest[T]]
  }
```

**It doesn't work**, as demonstrated in the following test case:

```
object TypeTag2Manifest {

  class Example {

    type T = Map[String, Int]
  }
  val example = new Example

}

class TypeTag2Manifest extends FunSpec {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.universe._
  import TypeTag2Manifest._

  it("can convert") {

    val t1 = implicitly[TypeTag[example.T]]
    val v1 = toManifest(t1)
    val v2 = implicitly[Manifest[example.T]]

    assert(v1 == v2)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map did not equal scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, Int]
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.tribbloids.spike.scala_spike.reflection.TypeTag2Manifest at (TypeTag2Manifest.scala:52)
Expected :scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, Int]
Actual   :scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

Evidently this indicates that type erasure has been plaguing the conversion, and TypeTag, despite being designed to avoid type erasure, can only resolve to the dependent type `example.T` without getting the correct type arguments from underlying type `Map[String, Int]`.

So what is the way to convert TypeTag and Manifest into each other that doesn't suck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace

```
toManifestRec(t.tpe).asInstanceOf[Manifest[T]]
```

with

```
toManifestRec(t.tpe.dealias).asInstanceOf[Manifest[T]]
```

this improves `toManifest` but not completely:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, int]
```

vs.

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, Int]
```

i.e. Java primitive `int` vs. `scala.Int`.

The problem is in the second `.runtimeClass` in

```
val clazz = ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t)).runtimeClass
```

`mirror.runtimeClass(t)` is `int`, `ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t))` is `Int` but `ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t)).runtimeClass` is again `int.`

So try to improve `toManifest` more

```
def toManifest[T: TypeTag]: Manifest[T] = {
  val t = typeTag[T]
  val mirror = t.mirror
  def toManifestRec(t: Type): Manifest[_] = {
    ClassTag[T](mirror.runtimeClass(t)) match {
      case ClassTag.Byte    => Manifest.Byte
      case ClassTag.Short   => Manifest.Short
      case ClassTag.Char    => Manifest.Char
      case ClassTag.Int     => Manifest.Int
      case ClassTag.Long    => Manifest.Long
      case ClassTag.Float   => Manifest.Float
      case ClassTag.Double  => Manifest.Double
      case ClassTag.Boolean => Manifest.Boolean
      case ClassTag.Unit    => Manifest.Unit
      case ClassTag.Object  => Manifest.Object
      case ClassTag.Nothing => Manifest.Nothing
      case ClassTag.Null    => Manifest.Null
      case classTag         =>
        val clazz = classTag.runtimeClass
        if (t.typeArgs.length >= 1) {
          val args = t.typeArgs.map(x => toManifestRec(x))
          ManifestFactory.classType(clazz, args.head, args.tail: _*)
        } else {
          ManifestFactory.classType(clazz)
        }
    }
  }
  toManifestRec(t.tpe.dealias).asInstanceOf[Manifest[T]]
}

val t1 = implicitly[TypeTag[example.T]] //TypeTag[TypeTag2Manifest.example.T]
val v1 = toManifest(t1) //scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, Int]
val v2 = implicitly[Manifest[example.T]] //scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String, Int]
v1 == v2 //true
```